# setAttribute() doesn't "remember" the value assigned to it's ID in a function if its a defined variable?

Tags: javascript, html

This function creates a unique label and corresponding delete button on the screen that, when pressed, deletes itself and the label by its unique ID. In order to be able to distinguish itself from other label-delete pairs it is assigned a unique ID based on the selection that caused its existence (from a select menu).

```
function saveSelection(selection) {
    var element = document.getElementById("div1");

    var del = document.createElement("button");
    del.type = "button";
    del.id = selection;
    del.setAttribute("onclick", "deleteSelection(selection)");
    del.appendChild(document.createTextNode("delete"));
    element.appendChild(del);
}

function deleteSelection(selection) {
    var element = document.getElementById("div1");
    element.removeChild(document.getElementById(selection));
    console.log("deleted");
}
```

The problem is, when I assign the selection to the buttons ID I have to refer to it by its variable name (actually called 'selection' in the function). When the delete button is pressed I suspect the code looks at the value passed in the onclick function and just sees 'selection' because it has "forgotten" what "selection" was, thus causing an error. Either this or I am not using proper syntax (lack/presence of ' or " quotes) and am thus passing/assigning it incorrectly.

Google Chrome's error console points out this line as the problem:

```
del.setAttribute("onclick", "deleteSelection(selection)");
```

specifially citing the 'selection' variable as being not defined in

```
deleteSelection(selection)
```

Comment: Please create a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) for people to play around with and include a link in your question. Include everything needed for a working sample, even if it doesn't quite work, including the html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`selection` is not a global variable - presumably, it's scoped to the function that creates the element. Inline handlers that reference variables can only reference global variables.

But inline handlers are *terrible practice* anyway, they're basically `eval` inside HTML markup - better to attach the handler properly with Javascript instead, and no need for any `id`s:

```js
document.querySelector('#add').onclick = function saveSelection() {
  var element = document.getElementById("div1");
  var del = document.createElement("button");
  del.type = "button";
  del.onclick = del.remove;
  del.textContent = 'delete';
  element.appendChild(del);
};
```

```html
<div id="add">add</div>
<div id="div1"></div>
```

Comment: I see. This did work, however I have two questions:<br> This syntax: 
    del.onclick = () => del.remove();<br> is extremely confusing and i've never seen it before, where does it come from and what is it doing? Obviously you know that del.onclick= deleteSelection; doesnt work.<br><br>Also, how could I change your code to also delete the associated label for the delete button (the 4 lines of which I didnt include)

Comment: The `del.onclick = () => del.remove()` that was there before is only an arrow function - very similar to a full-fledged `function() {` only more terse (and often preferable). But there's no need for that, as you can see in the edit - you can simply assign the `remove` function to the `onclick` property. Since you haven't posted your code for the label, there's no way of saying exactly how it would be removed along with the delete button, but you could probably pass the element as a parameter to `saveSelection` and call `remove` on it

Comment: Now you've edited that line to just say: del.onclick = del.remove;      but that doesn't work when I put it in. How did you come up with the code from before? Also, is it possible to put more than one onclick function in? Code for label is     var option = document.createElement("label");
    option.for=selection;
    option.appendChild(document.createTextNode(selection));
    element.appendChild(option);

Comment: It should work - just press `Run code snippet`, seems to be just fine, but if you have to use `del.onclick = () => del.remove();` that's fine too. If you want to add multiple listeners to a single element, use `addEventListener` instead.